# Jquery spoiler close second div when open first

Tags: jquery

I'm beginning jquery & i have small problem with code
when I open first div  the second div is not closed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.spoiler-text').hide()
    jQuery('.spoiler').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded").next().slideToggle()
    })

})
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96FY6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.spoiler-text').hide()
    jQuery('.spoiler').click(function () {
        var spoilerText = jQuery(this).next();
        jQuery('.spoiler-text').not(spoilerText).slideUp();        
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded").next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96FY6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer..

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.spoiler-text').hide()
            jQuery('.spoiler').click(function(){
                if ($(this).hasClass("folded")){
                    $(".spoiler-text").slideUp();
                     $(".unfolded").toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded");
                     $(this).toggleClass("folded").toggleClass("unfolded").next().slideDown();
                }
            })

        })
```

Here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96FY6/6/)